# How to compress picture just taken with React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, camera, compression, expo, media-library

I'm using the Camera component from expo and MediaLibrary to save the picture taken. My question is, how can I compress that image when saving it with MediaLibrary in the Galery? Im trying to compress it because later I will also be uploading that image to Firebase Storage. So far this is the code that I have right now working without compressing it:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

export default function App() {

  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [cameraRef, setCameraRef] = useState(null)
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }

  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={type} ref={ref => {
        setCameraRef(ref) ;
      }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            justifyContent: 'flex-end'
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{alignSelf: 'center', marginBottom: 20}} onPress={async() => {
            if(cameraRef){
              let photo = await cameraRef.takePictureAsync({ skipProcessing: true });
              MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(photo.uri);
            }
          }}>
            <View style={{ 
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderColor: 'white',
              height: 50,
              width:50,
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              borderRadius: 25,
              }}
            >
              <View style={{
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderColor: 'white',
                height: 40,
                width:40,
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                borderRadius: 25}} >
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**ImageManipulator comes with expo, you can compress, resize, rotate, crop and many more.**

```
import { ImageManipulator } from 'expo';

const manipResult = await ImageManipulator.manipulate(
    imageUri,
    [{ resize: { width: 640, height: 480 } }],
    { format: 'jpg' }
);
```

**Checkout https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/**

Answer (score 4):

`ImageManipulator` was moved to [`expo-image-manipulator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-image-manipulator) package. Updating your example:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

// New import
import * as ImageManipulator from 'expo-image-manipulator';

const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

export default function App() {

  // Same code as before

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={type} ref={ref => {
        setCameraRef(ref);
      }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            justifyContent: 'flex-end'
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{alignSelf: 'center', marginBottom: 20}} onPress={async() => {
            if(cameraRef) {
              let photo = await cameraRef.takePictureAsync({ skipProcessing: true });
              // New code here
              const manipResult = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
                photo.uri,
                [{ rotate: 90 }, { flip: ImageManipulator.FlipType.Vertical }],
                { compress: 1, format: ImageManipulator.SaveFormat.PNG }
          );
              MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(manipResult.uri);
            }
          }}>
            <View style={{ /* Same style properties here */ }}
              >
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[More details here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it with ImagePicker

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import {manipulateAsync} from 'expo-image-manipulator';

   const image = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        presentationStyle: 0, // for ios 
        allowsEditing: true,
    });

    if (image.hasOwnProperty('uri')) {
        const manipulateResult = await manipulateAsync(
             image.uri,
            [],
            { compress: 0.2 } // from 0 to 1 "1 for best quality"
        );
        setImage(manipulateResult.uri);
    }
```